# How do I turn my current page displaying profiles into one that uses infinite scrolling?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a Firestore database with a heap of profile documents and I'm displaying them on the webpage through v-for. I've been trying for a while now to get just 4 documents at a time and then on scrolling, get another four to increase user experience.

I originally tried getting just four documents but then I had no idea how to get the next four instead of just getting the same for over and over again. I've also tried many different examples online but none of them work either.

Here's what I have so far on the JavaScript page which gets the profiles from Firestore:

```js
const getPremium = () => {
    const Premium = ref([])
    const error = ref(null)

    const load = async () => {
        try{
            const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(4).get()

            Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
                console.log(doc.data())
                return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
        }
        catch (err){
            error.value = err.message
            console.log(error.value)
        }
    }

    return { Premium, error, load}
}

export default getPremium
```

And here is the Vue page which I want to show all the profiles with infinite scrolling:

```js
<script setup>
import getPremium from "../Composables/getPremium.js";
const {Premium, error, load} = getPremium();
load();
</script>

<template>
<br> 
 <div class="grid ...">

 <div v-for ="Premiums in Premium" :key="Premiums.id">
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'Samplepremium', params: { id: Premiums.id }}">
     <div class= "hover:scale-105 ...">
       <br>
         <p class="text-xl">{{ Premiums.name }}</p>
           <div class="relative">
             <img :src= "Premiums.Pic1"  class="object-contain ...">
             <p class="bg-red-700 text-slate-300 ...">{{ Premiums.det1 }}</p>
             <p class="bg-red-700 text-slate-300 ..."> {{ Premiums.det2 }} </p>
           </div>
           <div class="grid grid-cols-2 grid-rows-fit text-left ml-6">
             <p>Age:</p>
             <p>{{ Premiums.det3 }}</p>
             <p>Location:</p>
             <p>{{ Premiums.det4 }}</p>
             <p>Rates:</p>
             <p>{{ Premiums.det5 }} /hr</p>
             <p>Phone:</p>
             <p>{{ Premiums.det6 }}</p>
           </div>
           <br>
     </div>
   </router-link>
 </div>

</template>
```

I've taken out any attempts I've made to fetch another 4 as they just continually get the same 4 and don't put any others on the page. If anyone can show me how to do this with this code it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need an offset when querying new data. I don't have much experience in firebase but it should be startAt method. What you can try is to keep the current offset of your data and when you scroll to the point where you need to load new data just call the method with offset's value.

Here you can read more about startAt method.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

Giving you an example what you can try:

```
const load = async (offset = 0) {
     try{
        const res = await projectFirestore.collection('Premium').limit(4).startAt(offset).get()

        Premium.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
            return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
        })
    }
    catch (err){
        error.value = err.message
        console.log(error.value)
    }
}
```

Now you need a scroll method to detect the element's position with user's browser window. When you get to that point of the page you can call the function and add the offset parameter to it.